# How to pass a PHP variable to an external javascript file

Tags: javascript, php

Please forgive me for the noob question and if you decide to help I need an answer that a noob can actually understand.
I have php script which sends emails via the php mailer function.
When emails are sent correctly I want to be able to pass a variable to my app.js file located in my website folder.
this is my php script:

```
        $mail->send();
        $alert = '<div class="sentMessage active">
                    <i class="far fa-times-circle"></i>
                    <p>Thank you! Your message was successfully sent.</p>
                  </div>';
        header('Location: index.php');
    } catch (Exception $e){
       $alert = '<div class="alert-error">
                    <span>'.$e->getMessage().'</span>
                    </div>';
    }
}
```

now instead of having php creating the div as in the script above I just want it to send a true or false to my javascript so that I can control what happens within my javascript.

How can I do this?

How to do I allow my app.js to know what is happening in my php script?
Again sorry for th noob question!

Comment: In my index.php file I have
```
<?php include 'sendEmail.php'; ?>
``` and that is what allows php to interact with the index.php file how do I do the same for my app.js?

Comment: use ajax, then its trivial to respond with json which includes status and error

Comment: Sorry I'd like to stick to vanilla is since I don't know Ajax

Comment: ajax is vanilla

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to notify the user of successful mail you can send a variable named `mailSent` in the query parameters that would be a boolean

```
$mail->send();
      $alert = '<div class="sentMessage active">
                <i class="far fa-times-circle"></i>
                <p>Thank you! Your message was successfully sent.</p>
                </div>';
       header('Location: index.php?mailSent=true'); // note the mailSent param
} catch (Exception $e){
   $alert = '<div class="alert-error">
                <span>'.$e->getMessage().'</span>
                </div>';
}
```

In your app.js file, you can access the query parameter, it'll depend on what framework you're using

For vanilla JS you can use

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const myParam = urlParams.get('mailSent'); // mailSent: true then show a successful alert or something
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I'm using vanilla JS no framework.
So you are saying I should set a variable in php script. A variable which will be a boolean. I understand that but I cannot work out how to access that variable from within my JS app. Sorry if I'm slow.